# Query String error when trying to save the data using jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, query-string

ASP.NET MVC4  ||  C#

I have a MenuRole page which displays list of menu from the database.Users have to select a Role and corresponding menus from the page.All was going well but when i tried to save the data I am getting the following error.
`'The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long'`.I an using `jquery ajax` for saving the detaiils and I found out that the parameters are passing as querystring from view to the controller which I think is not an ideal scenario.

Is this the default behaviour of passing data when using jquery ajax in the form?

How can the issue be solved?

**error message**

[image]

**Requested URL**

[image]

**JQuery ajax for saving the details**

```
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var formData = $('#frmRoles').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("Add","MenuSettings")",
                data: formData,
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    toastr.success(data.message)                        
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    toastr.error(data.message);
                }
            });
        })
```

Comment: Do you have a method `Add` marked with `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your input mate..I decorated the add method with httppost but forgot to decorate the Html form  with post method

Comment: You don't need to decorate the form - its `FormMethod.Post` by default. And I suspect you must also be doing both the standard submit and the ajax post if that's happening - is `$("#btnSubmit")` a submit button? - if so add `return false;` as the last line of the script to cancel the default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string means your making a GET call (and exceeding the query string limit). Assuming you button is a submit button, then your making both a normal submit (the form method must be `FormMethod.Get`) and the ajax post.

To prevent the default submit, add `return false;` to the end of your script

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var formData = $('#frmRoles').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        ....
    });
    return false; // add this
})
```

Comment: Thats it ... @super steve